# ¿Cómo consigo que un CheckBox se habilite cuando otro esté Checked?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo dos `Checkbox` y necesito que uno se pueda clicar sólo cuando el otro esté `Cheked`

La línea de `CheckBox` que estoy usando es esta:

```
<tr >
    <td>Cobetura</td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox id="CbCoberturaR" runat="server" Height="15" Width="15"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="CbCoberturaC" Height="15" Width="15" Enabled="<%= CheckCorrecta()%>"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

El método que estoy usando es este:

```
Public ReadOnly Property CheckCorrecta() As Boolean
    Get
        If (CbCoberturaR.Checked = True) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    End Get
End Property
```

¿Alguien me puede indicar porqué no funciona?
¿Cómo hago para que esto funcione?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que signar [`OnCheckedChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.oncheckedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) en el checkbox `CbCoberturaR` que se ejecuta cuando la propiedad `Checked` cambia:

```
<tr >
    <td>Cobetura</td>
    <td>
       <asp:CheckBox id="CbCoberturaR" runat="server" Height="15" Width="15"
     OnCheckedChanged="CoberturaR_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
    />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" id="CbCoberturaC" Height="15" Width="15"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Y en el evento modificas la propiedad `Enabled` de `CbCoberturaC` en base al estado de `CbCoberturaR`. Asi siempre que des Checked sobre el primer checkbox, el segundo se habilitara/deshabilitara en base a la propiedad check del primero:

```
Protected Sub CoberturaR_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    CbCoberturaC.Enabled = CbCoberturaR.Checked
End Sub
```